# how i can access connection variable in function

Tags: php, oop

i want to access $conn in class mention in bellow.

conn_file.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conn = new mysqli($servername,  $username,  $password);
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection Failed :".$conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

class.function.php

```
<?php
include_once 'conn_file.php';
class all_function
{
    public function something()
    {
        $data = $conn->real_escape_string("data");
        return $data;
    }
}
?>
```

The above gives me the following error:
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in class.function.php on line 7

Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in class.function.php on line 7

Comment: Pass it as argument ?!

Comment: Or with `global` statement

Comment: @u_mulder No, that's not a good idea.

Comment: I know, but it's used here quite often(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `class` for connection. Example:

**In conn_file.php**

```
class DbConfig{
    public static $servername = "localhost";
    public static $username = "root";
    public static $password = "";

    public static function getCon(){
        $conn = new mysqli(self::$servername,  self::$username,  self::$password);

        if($conn->connect_error){
            die("Connection Failed :".$conn->connect_error);
        }

        return $conn;
    }
}
```

**In class.function.php**

```
include_once 'conn_file.php';
class all_function
{
    public function something()
    {
        $conn = DbConfig::getCon();
        $data = $conn->real_escape_string("data");
        return $data;
    }
}
```